# Always Sign-In into Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I usually use Visual Studio 2008, but every time I start Visual Studio 2013 I get a notification that tells me an error occurred and I have to sign in again. Is this the normal behavior or is it really an error?

It is annoying. How can  I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Does it give you more details about the error? if I were you, I would apply the latest Update and then clear your internet cookies...and finally sign in again into VS2013. Be sure to run Visual Studio in Administrator mode.

Comment: I will try deleting the cookies. No it does not say anything else about the error. That is the problem! And I can not recreate it right now, because I just logged in and it is working for the moment (probably in a few days I will get the error again.)

Answer (score 0):

This is an error I've had before when not running Visual Studio in Administrator mode, try running it in Administrator mode. Also, do ensure your Visual Studio is up to date.

Comment: VS is set to automatically start as admin (it does work) and it is up-to-date.